# cannot use dot notation on JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function like this

```
data = JSON.parse(data)
```

where `data` is first, a string like this

```
"{\"content\":\"Hello there\",\"uid\":\"OoIEfsgabT89EJw\",\"createdAt\":1451586225268,\"user\":{\"avatar\":\"https://avatars.com/123?v=3\",\"login\":\"login\",\"name\":\"Username\",\"uid\":123}}"�
```

and the data transformed is now

```
{"content":"Hello there","uid":"OoIEfsgabT89EJw","createdAt":1451586225268,"user":{"avatar":"https://avatars.com/126?v=3","login":"login","name":"Username","uid":123}}
```

when I try to access `data.uid` I see `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

edit: the code

```
addItem: function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data)

  console.log("Adding: "+data)
  console.log("Adding: "+data.uid)
},
```

edit2: the JSON was double encoded.
doing `data = JSON.parse(data)` two times solved, but this is completely wrong. What else can I do?

Comment: Guessing your JSON is actually double encoded. Does it work if you do this? `data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))`

Comment: yes, you were right. just edited the question

Comment: Then the answer is to fix it on the server. Something is wrong if it's getting encoded twice.

Comment: I send to the frontend a JSON string...I don't see what should be fixed on the server. seems like the frontend is parsing again

Comment: Yeah, can't really help there without knowing more details but the question doesn't involve the JavaScript end. What you're doing there is correct once you fix the encoding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using double quotes `"` in beginning and end that will create a string variable and not JSON, you should use it directely.

**Working example:**

```js
var data = {"content":"Hello there","uid":"OoIEfsgabT89EJw","createdAt":1451586225268,"user":{"avatar":"https://avatars.com/126?v=3","login":"login","name":"Username","uid":123}};

console.log(data.uid); //OoIEfsgabT89EJw
```

**Not working example :**

```js
var data='{"content":"Hello there","uid":"OoIEfsgabT89EJw","createdAt":1451586225268,"user":{"avatar":"https://avatars.com/126?v=3","login":"login","name":"Username","uid":123}}'

console.log(data.uid); //undefined
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If he's using JSON, the data is most likely not coming from within the program. And in fact if it is a string in the program, then it *is JSON*.

Comment: What you mean by _ if it is a string, then it is JSON_?

Comment: Because JSON is UTF encoded text and the only way to represent UTF text in a JavaScript program is by using a string.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what JSON is for. Your second example now shows JSON data being stored in the `data` variable. If you look at the question again, he's parsing it using `JSON.parse()`, so it should work. However, it's very unusual to embed JSON data directly in a JavaScript program like that.

Comment: Okay i see that the OP is updated and `JSON.parse()` just added in update.